# Is there a way to have specific constraints depending on device or screen orientation?

Tags: ios, uikit, storyboard, constraints

So say I have a label I want to put above a UIImageView. Easy. But when I turn the screen orientation to landscape, I would rather the label is next to the image view because suddenly there's more horizontal space than vertical.

Now consider that I constrain these based on an iPhone 15, and then decide to switch to an iPad Air. Suddenly the layouts that looked great on the iPhone have shrunken features and loads of empty space.

I know I can set different constraints based on screen orientation if setup programmatically, and I know that if I use auto layout constraints I can figure out something that looks ok on many devices.

The thing is, I would really like to utilize that extra iPad space to make a unique layout. On top of that, I'm not used to setting constraints programmatically, as I use the storyboard buttons instead.

With that in mind, the two things I'm mostly concerned about are:

- Is there a way to set completely different constraints for each object based on BOTH screen orientation AND device type?
- If there is, is there any way to set it up using storyboards?

The constraints don't have to *run* using storyboards. For example, maybe there's a way to set it up in storyboards, then convert it to code afterward so I don't have to write all constraints from scratch.

Any ideas for how to make this work? I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Sure - it is generally referred to as "Adaptive Layout" and you can manage it by setting different constraints based on "Size Classes." Head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `xcode adaptive layout` -- you'll find lots and lots to read about it. Designing your UI to adapt to different device layouts is not a particularly simple task, so be prepared to spend a good bit of time learning about it.